# How do you make global variables for the height and width of the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to set variables for the height and width of the screen in a variables file so I can access them from all my other files.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

BuildContext context = context;

double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

This however results in the app not running and the return message

> Reading static variable 'context' during its initialization

Comment: Use a normal `class` and set `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` as a static members

Answer (score 7):

You need a valid `BuildContext` instance, and you can't get one outside of a `Widget`'s `build` method.  You instead could *declare* global variables and *initialize* them later:

```dart
double? screenWidth;
double? screenHeight;

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Initialize `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` only if they haven't
    // already been set.
    screenWidth ??= MediaQuery.of(context)?.size.width;
    screenHeight ??= MediaQuery.of(context)?.size.height;

    ...
  }
}
```

In your case, you alternatively could use [`Window.physicalSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/physicalSize.html):

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

late double screenWidth;
late double screenHeight;

void main() {
  // Convert from physical pixels to Flutter's logical pixels.
  screenWidth = ui.window.physicalSize.width / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
  screenHeight = ui.window.physicalSize.height / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
  ...
}
```

Also note that in both of these examples, the screen size would be set *once*, so the values won't be updated on their own if, say, the screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do it that way, take a look at this example. Create a class

```
class MyUtility {
  BuildContext context;

  MyUtility(this.context) : assert (context != null);

  double get width => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double get height => MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
}
```

And this is how you use it, when you want to get `width` and `height`, you would simply use

```
double width = MyUtility(context).width;
double height = MyUtility(context).height;
```

Make sure the `context` you pass should be after `build()` has executed else you'll get error.

Comment: It's not really clear how the `MyUtility` is that helpful for what the OP is asking.  Anywhere `MyUtility` could be used, `MediaQuery.of()` could be used directly.

Comment: What OP was asking isn't possible to achieve, I thought he must be having a class like MyUtility and I showed him how he could have got away with width and height